# Advanced Pricing is missing in Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento2, pricing, advanced-pricing

This is my product adding screen of Magento now.
[image]

And the old screen was
[image]

No more "Advanced Pricing", and I have "Dynamic SKU", "Dynamic Price",...
It is correct ?, because I am in Simple Product, it is really strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue & fixed it. It is because some product attributes are set to wrong product types, while some necessary attributes are missing from some product types. May be it is because the upgrade ran incorrectly somehow...

Therefore, "Advanced Pricing" is missing, while there are "Dynamic SKU", "Dynamic Price",... that should not be exist in "Simple Product"

So:

- Advanced Pricing is corresponded to "tier_price", "special_price", "special_from_date", "special_to_date", "msrp", "msrp_display_actual_price_type", "cost",... & these are missing from Simple product type => need to assign these to this type again.
- "Dynamic SKU", "Dynamic Price", "Dynamic Weight" are belongs to only Bundle product type, while these are set to Simple product type too => need to unset these from Simple type.

Then everything works well again :)

Answer (score 2):

Its showing at my end , i have a latest version of magento 2.1.8

And on Product page advanced pricing is showing and works well!!

**Below is the screenshot for the same :**

[image]

**Note :**

1. Check your browser console , you might have js error or issues
2. Check your error log as well might helps you
3. If still not shown then installed it again or update manually
   without using composer might helps you
4. You can also refer magento 2.1.8 release notes - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.8CE.html